# Selenium Webdriver C# Unable to locate an element on the "active" dropdown class list

Tags: selenium, automation

I am on the beginner level if it goes for the selenium Webdriver in C#. I can locate elements, write simple scripts in order to input some value, withdraw it, compare and etc. I can also get values from the dropdown list by SelectElement class and so far I have not had any issues.

Recently one of our systems was refactored to React JS and most of my automation tests have stopped working.

Right now I have been struggling with a simple logout operation. I will please my issue below, and I would be grateful for any tips or suggestions.

The hard thing is that I can not locate the logout link which is located in the dropdown list, however, the code for it looks as below. Before you click on the link which acts as an action for the drop-down list it looks like this:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        UserName UserLast
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/Account/Logout">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="user-login" class="hidden">UserName.UserLast</div>
    <div id="user-email" class="hidden">UserName.UserLast@companyname.com</div>
</li>
```

When a User clicks on the   the code changes to this one below:

```
<li class="dropdown open">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        UserName UserLast
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/Account/Logout">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="user-login" class="hidden">UserName.UserLast</div>
    <div id="user-email" class="hidden">UserName.UserLast@companyname.com</div>
</li>
```

My test is quite simple, locate the Logout "button/link", click on it and perform the logout operation. Now I have started of location the action link which looks like this:

```
 [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li[2]/a")]
        private IWebElement userDropdown;
```

And my logout method looks like that's,

```
 public void LogOut()
        {
            userDropdown.Click();
            var userDropDownList = Browser.WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li[2]/ul"));
            var logoutButton = userDropDownList.FindElement(By.LinkText("Logout"));
            logoutButton.Click();

        }
```

I perform the click operation on the link, look for the list with the Logout, use the click operation. Still my test does not work and I am not getting any errors at all but the logout operation is not done. I think that the issue here is not the drop-down  list is not visible by selenium. I have not tried the SelectElement class because this example is not a select element or maybe I am wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to perform `click()` on 2 elements to logout:

- Identify the dropdown:

  ```
  [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//li[@class='dropdown']/a[@class='dropdown-toggle']/span[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-user']")]
  private IWebElement userDropdown;
  ```
- `logOut` method:

  ```
  public void logOut()
  {
      userDropdown.Click();
      var logoutButton = Browser.WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@class='dropdown']//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']/li/a[@href='/Account/Logout']"));
      logoutButton.Click();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

so first things first make sure you've scrolled the item to view

```
var js = (IJavascriptExecutor)driver;
string idOfLinkToMakeDropDownOpen = "whatever the id is"
IWebElement obj = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='idOfLinkToMakeDropDownOpen']"));
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", obj);

obj.Click();
```

Now the drop down should be open so click it

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("descendant::a[text() = 'Logout']")).Click();
```

That should click it. You'll probably want to watch it to see if opens the drop down. You also may need to wait a second after the dom to change after having opened the drop down. That would work something like this:

```
IWebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
```

after obj.Click(); you do this line:

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Xpath("descendant::li[@class = 'dropdown open']"));
```